# Relationship Field Dropdown Values more than {title} in Backend

Tags: categories, relationships, drop-down

I have a relationship Field. I would like to show the category in front of the title within the Dropdown-List. Any plugin? Other Solution? Or do I have to alter the core of EE relationship field?

I'd like to see this in the dropdown list:

```
Category A -> {title_1}
Category A -> {title_2}
Category A -> {title_3}
Category B -> {title_4}
Category B -> {title_5}
```

Any Hints?

Comment: Looks like there is an opportunity for someone to make an add-on and sell it...I came across the same issue and went with the MX Title Control option myself. If you enable the debug/output tool, you can see the SQL query and file that EE is using to generate the dropdown. The hack shouldn't be too difficult, but the issue I saw is that they use a table that only holds the titles and nothing else, so you'd have to join it with another table to grab other information that you'd need.

Answer (score 0):

No add-on I know of will do this, and even alternate relationship fieldtypes like Playa don't allow you to customize the item titles on the publish screen.

Unfortunately, hacking core would be a) a bad idea, and b) require extra queries to get the category data for each item as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know to do anything here is to use an addon like https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-title-control to actually change the title of the entries, so then they will display with the desired info in the relationship fieldtypes.

You may need to then create a 'Page Title' field for use in displaying on the site.